# HZ_CUST_SITE_USES no rows returned

Tags: oracle, role-based-access-control

When query the following table it returns zero records.

```
SQL> select count(*) from HZ_CUST_SITE_USES;

COUNT(*)
----------
        0

SQL>
```

can you please help me some one

Comment: How about `select count(*) from HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_ALL` ?

Comment: I'm able to get the records from HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_ALL, but why  not able get any records from HZ_CUST_SITE_USES?

Answer (score 1):

**Per My Oracle Support (Doc ID 787677.1), You Have a Security Policy Enabled on the APPS Owned Synonym**

This is a standard set-up associated with `APPS@ERP` owned synonyms in an Oracle R12 environment.

First, confirm that the `APPS@ERP` owned synonym when queried without setting an org specific security policy context will result in an empty set:

```
APPS@ERP>SELECT COUNT(1) FROM HZ_CUST_SITE_USES;
COUNT(1)  
0
```

Next confirm that a security policy has been applied to this `APPS@ERP` owned synonym:

```
APPS@erp>SELECT object_name,
  2    policy_group,
  3    policy_name,
  4    PACKAGE,
  5    FUNCTION,
  6    sel,
  7    enable
  8  FROM dba_policies
  9  WHERE object_name = 'HZ_CUST_SITE_USES';
OBJECT_NAME        POLICY_GROUP  POLICY_NAME  PACKAGE    FUNCTION      SEL  ENABLE  
HZ_CUST_SITE_USES  SYS_DEFAULT   ORG_SEC      MO_GLOBAL  ORG_SECURITY  YES  YES
```

Just confirm that the object type is a synonym:

```
APPS@erp>SELECT owner,
  2    object_name,
  3    object_type
  4  FROM DBA_OBJECTS
  5  WHERE 1         =1
  6  AND OBJECT_NAME = 'HZ_CUST_SITE_USES';
OWNER  OBJECT_NAME        OBJECT_TYPE  
APPS   HZ_CUST_SITE_USES  SYNONYM
```

Query the `APPS@ERP` view associated with the `AR` owned table, `HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_ALL`:

```
APPS@erp>--APPS owned view r12.2
APPS@erp>SELECT ORG_ID, COUNT(1) FROM HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_ALL GROUP BY ORG_ID;
ORG_ID  COUNT(1)  
123     458       
456     2658      
789     1210
```

Once the context is set for a session (org_id is 456), one can query results for that org_id:

```
APPS@erp>--set policy
APPS@erp>EXEC mo_global.set_policy_context('S', 456);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

APPS@erp>SELECT COUNT(1) FROM HZ_CUST_SITE_USES;
COUNT(1)  
2658
```